# Tikz trees - line feature

Tags: tikz-trees

In my MWE :

- why `line width=0pt` doesn't work ?
- why the dashed argument on a level leeks on the next ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=5mm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=32mm,line width=0pt},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=16mm,dashed},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,level distance=12mm},
    %level 4/.style={sibling distance=7mm},
    %every fit/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt},
    grow=right]

\scriptsize
\node {$\bullet$}
child {node {P}
        child {node{PP}
            child {node{PPP}}
            child {node{PPF}}
        }
        child {node{PF}
            child {node{PFP}}
            child {node{PFF}}
        }
    }
child {node {F}
        child {node{FP}
            child {node{FPP}}
            child {node{FPF}}
        }
        child {node{FF}
            child {node{FFP}}
            child {node{FFF}}
        }
    } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: line width=0pt is invisible. try instead such it definition to use draw=none (effect should be the same).

Comment: @Zarko Doesn't work at all.

Comment: @HarishKumar Maybe you can cheat a png picture ;-) but in pdf with evince viewer, the line is still here.

Comment: @HarishKumar what does it mean ? sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What does 'scrap that' means, I appologize for my poor english, I can't understand what you said.

Comment: Hehe, it means "scrap my previous comment" as it is wrong. :) And don't apologise for english. Many of us are not native english speakers too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to change the `edge from parent` style

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=5mm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=32mm,
      edge from parent/.style={draw=none}},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=16mm,
      edge from parent/.append style={draw,dashed}},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,level distance=12mm,
      edge from parent/.append style={solid}},
    %level 4/.style={sibling distance=7mm},
    %every fit/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt},
    grow=right]

\scriptsize
\node {$\bullet$}
child {node {P}
        child {node{PP}
            child {node{PPP}}
            child {node{PPF}}
        }
        child {node{PF}
            child {node{PFP}}
            child {node{PFF}}
        }
    }
child {node {F}
        child {node{FP}
            child {node{FPP}}
            child {node{FPF}}
        }
        child {node{FF}
            child {node{FFP}}
            child {node{FFF}}
        }
    } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way I can apply the `edge from parent` style only to one level and have all others assume the default?

Comment: If only the second `level` should be `dashed` you could use: `level/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw,solid}},` and `level 2/.style={edge from parent/.append style={dashed}}`.